# How to know if chat gpt's DOM's mutation is complete

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, openai-api

I am trying to create a chrome extention for chatgpt which converts the text of gpt response to voice. So as the first step i tried to log gpt's text in console. From inspect elements i have identified that the text elements (< p >) are stored in a div with class name .markdown, so i wrote the follwoing code:

But the problem is that it is printing before the gpt gives complete response, hence it is only printing a small part of the response.

```
function handleMutations(mutationsList, observer) {
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach((addedNode) => {
        if (addedNode instanceof HTMLElement && addedNode.classList.contains('markdown')) {
          console.log('markdown', addedNode);
          const paragraphNodes = addedNode.querySelectorAll('p');
          paragraphNodes.forEach((paragraphNode) => {
            console.log('text in', paragraphNode.innerHTML);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

const observerConfig = { childList: true, subtree: true };

const observer = new MutationObserver(handleMutations);

observer.observe(document.body, observerConfig);
```

i want to print after the whole thing is  loaded.

I'm sorry if there are any mistakes in my question, do ask me if i left any gaps in the question.
Thank you.